# Same function name in different namespaces

Tags: c++

Suppose I have different namespaces
like apple namespace and orange namespace but both of the namespaces contain a function called myfunction().

What will happen when I call myfunction() in main()?

Comment: Most likely the name won't be found and the code won't compile. But maybe post some example code, because the details matter.

Comment: Qualify the function call with the namespace you intend, i.e. apply::myfunction() or orange::myfunction()

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is exactly what namespaces have been introduced for.

In your `main()`, or in general in the *global namespace*, you will be able to select wich `myfunctions` has to be called:

```
int main()
{
     apple::myfunction(); // call the version into the apple namespace
     orange::myfunction(); // call the orange one
     myfunction(); // error: there is no using declaration / directive
}
```

In case of a *using directive* (`using namespace apple`) or a *using declaration* (`using apple::myfunction`), the last line of the main would have called the version inside the namespace `apple`. If both versions of `myfunction` were in scope, the last line would produce an error again, because in that case you would have to specify which function has to be called.

Comment: And if you use something like `using namespace apple` *and* `using namespace orange`? That's the last thing for the complete answer I guess.

Comment: @Timo in that case the call is ambiguous and the compiler must reject it.

Comment: so if you perform **using namespace apple; using namespace orange; int main(){ myfunction(...);}**, you will get a compiler error?

Comment: For completeness, you could add that if there is an un-namespaced function, and you're currently inside a namespace, you can write `::myfunction();`

Comment: @MrLister I think your comment explain it pretty well ;)

Comment: @MichaelGoh: if the function signatures are different enough that they can be told apart and the call is correct for one and not the other, there's no ambiguity.  If the signatures are the same or are similar enough, then the call is ambiguous.

Comment: When both namespaces are pulled in with a using declaration the compiler **must issue a diagnostic**. That's the only formal requirement; it can then go ahead and compile the program, although the behavior when that happens is implementation specific. I don't know of a compiler that does that; the typical response is to reject the program, but that's not required by the language definition.

Answer (score 5):

Consider following example.

```
namespace Gandalf{

    namespace Frodo{
         bool static hasMyPrecious(){ // _ZN7Gandalf5FrodoL13hasMyPreciousEv
            return true;
        }
    };

    bool static hasMyPrecious(){ // _ZN7GandalfL13hasMyPreciousEv
        return true;
    }
};

namespace Sauron{
    bool static hasMyPrecious(){ // _ZN5SauronL13hasMyPreciousEv
        return true;
    }
};

bool hasMyPrecious(){ // _Z13hasMyPreciousv
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    if( Gandalf::Frodo::hasMyPrecious() || // _ZN7Gandalf5FrodoL13hasMyPreciousEv
        Gandalf::hasMyPrecious()        ||  // _ZN7GandalfL13hasMyPreciousEv
        Sauron::hasMyPrecious()          || // _ZN5SauronL13hasMyPreciousEv
        hasMyPrecious()) // _Z13hasMyPreciousv
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

As per namespace in which function is **declared**, compiler generates unique identity of each function called Mangled Name which is nothing but encoding of namespace scope in which function is defined, function name, return type and actual parameters.  see comments. As you create calls to this functions each function call looks for same mangled signature, if not found Compiler reports error.

Try Experimenting with clang -emit-llvm -S -c main.cpp -o main.ll if you are interested in internal working.

Comment: Please note that the standard does not specify any style of name mangling, nor does it actually even mention it, as far as I can tell.  Your examples are correct for G++, but MSVC does it differently, and I'd imagine Intel does it yet another way.  It's fine to illustrate with examples, but it should be made clear, when those examples are not portable, nor standard, that you cannot rely on that behavior, because it is implementation-defined.

Comment: yes. @Elkvis thanks for pointing out.   This Mapping of Scope are implementation defined and varies with compiler. Example is to illustrate how Scope and function inside scope relate to each other. Surely algorithm for **NameLookUp** changes, may be simple table based! but at end we are looking at functions that appears to have same name. and it's easy to learn this concepts with clang hence last Tip :)

Comment: Completely OT, but shoudn't "Soron" be "Sauron" ?

Comment: indeed ;) u got me there!